# Will an Amulet of Proof against Detection and Location protect an invisible character from being observed by True Sight or Robe of Eyes?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, invisibility, divination

Will an Amulet of Proof against Detection and Location protect an invisible character from being observed directly with divination magic?

I get that the Amulet would prevent the wearer from being detected by location/scrying type spells, but would it also protect them from being detected in ordinary line-of-sight by somebody with an effect that would allow them to see invisible, like Truesight or wearing a Robe of Eyes?

From [the description of the item](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/amulet-of-proof-against-detection-and-location):

> While wearing this amulet, you are hidden from divination magic. You can't be targeted by such magic or perceived through magical scrying sensors.

Does being looked at by somebody who can see invisible creatures count as being the "target" of the magic?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do Nondetection and Invisibility protect you from True Seeing?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/80845/do-nondetection-and-invisibility-protect-you-from-true-seeing)

Comment: @RyanThompson Not a dupe. OP isn't asking about *True Seeing*, just True Sight and the Robe of Eyes.

Comment: @NautArch Yeah, you're right. Looking at the details of the question, it's not just about diviniation magic (contrary to the title), but also other effects that can see invisible things. Although the question about whether the invisible creature counts as a "target" *is* answered by the question I linked.

Answer (score 11):

## No, it will not protect from standard True Sight or the Robe of Eyes

The [Amulet of Proof against Detection and Location](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/amulet-of-proof-against-detection-and-location) only says that you are:

> hidden from divination magic. You can't be targeted by such magic or perceived through magical scrying sensors.

### Not divination magic or magical scrying sensors

Standard Truesight and the [Robe of Eyes](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/robe-of-eyes) just allow you to see Invisible creatures. There is no divination magic involved and neither are Magical Scrying sensors - they are just things that provide the ability to see invisible creatures.

### It's all about the source of True Sight/seeing invisible

It would work against True Sight delivered via the spell [True Seeing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-seeing) as that is specifically divination magic which the amulet protects against.

If the source of whatever gives a creature the ability to see invisible is directly associated with divination magic or magical scrying, then it would work. But that connection must be explicitly stated in order for it to work.

Comment: In previous editions (3.0, 3.5) Robe of Eyes registered as "Moderate divination". Was this changed in 5?

Comment: @Mołot That is correct. See the link to the Robe and it shows the full text of it. In 5e, the robe simply provides the functions described (darkvision, advantage on sight-based perception checks, and the ability to see the ethereal plane and invisible things.)

Answer (score 5):

### You are protected from divination spells and magical scrying sensors.

Both True Seeing and See Invisibility are divination spells, so they would have no effect.

Senses that are natural (ancient dragon's natural truesight) or granted by items are not considered spells, and thus you are not protected from them (unless the item specifies you are using it to cast the spell, or is based on scrying). Using your example, Robe of Eyes wouldn't be affected by the amulet.

Comment: "Senses that are granted by items are not considered spells, and thus you are not protected from them"

Comment: His question is not specific to True Sight or Robe of Eyes. Those were both examples he gave that grant the ability to see invisible individuals, and asked if things like these bypass the Amulet.

Comment: Amulet description says *you are hidden from divination magic*, not *you are hidden from divination spells*. How is *"are not considered spells"* relevant to the question and amulet?

Comment: Because in 5e, spells are the only form of magic that has a mechanical tie to a magical school. Natural senses, environmental effects, and item-based magic do not have school associations in 5e.

Answer (score 2):

### Looking at someone counts as "targeting" them (according to Jeremy Crawford)

Going purely by the rules as written, it's not clear whether protection against targeting by divination spells would protect you from spells that the caster casts on their self that then grant new senses, such as *see invisibility* or *true seeing*. However, Jeremy Crawford has [clarified](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/786625163831848960) on Twitter<sup>1</sup> that in such cases, you are still protected:

> The nondetection spell hides you from divination magic. True seeing is a divination spell.

The *nondetection* spell grants a similar benefit to the Amulet:

> The target can't be targeted by any divination magic

So JC's ruling should apply to the Amulet as well. **This means that divination spells like *true seeing* will not enable a creature to see you, even if they don't explicitly "target" you.**

### Senses and abilities not based on divination magic function normally

As the other answers have covered adequately, the Amulet offers no protection against senses and abilities that are not based on divination magic. This includes the Robe of Eyes, unless your DM rules that this magic item *is* divination-based, which would not be unreasonable. It also includes creatures with a natural ability to see invisible things.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note: JC's Tweets are [no longer considered official rulings](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/140221/with-the-2019-sage-advice-compendium-release-are-jeremy-crawfords-tweets-consi). I can't find this particular ruling in the Sage Advice Compendium, so it can be considered semi-official at best, hence the parenthetical qualifier in the heading.

Comment: Why do you think it's reasonable for a DM to say that the Robe of Eyes is divination magic anymoreso than having True Sight is divination magic?

Comment: @NautArch Well, the Robe is explicitly magical, unlike natural truesight. I guess by RAW magic items generally don't have explicit associations with specific schools of magic, although I've heard DMs make *ad hoc* rulings when players looked at magic items using *detect magic* (e.g. transmutation for +1 weapons). If I was playing in a game and the DM told me the Robe of Eyes radiated divination magic, I don't think I'd see that as out of the ordinary. So that line was intended as a warning that "your DM may decide differently".

Comment: Gotcha. I guess I was just thinking more along the lines that it's not saying you are casting *true seeing*, so it's not that type of divination magic. It's just granting you an ability that isn't tied to a magical school and tying it to a school so it falls into another category would be a bridge too far for me.