# How does an Amulet of Proof against Detection and Location interact with the Detect Magic spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

One of my players got his hand on an [Amulet of Proof against Detection and Location](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/amulet-of-proof-against-detection-and-location), which hides him from divination magic. The description says:

> While wearing this amulet, you are hidden from divination magic. You can't be targeted by such magic or perceived through magical scrying sensors.

Does this mean that [*detect magic*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/detect-magic) (a divination spell) does not show anything on someone that wears this amulet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## *Detect Magic* would not work on the creature, but may work on items on that the creature is wearing/carrying

### Detecting magic on the creature wearing it

The quote you provided for the **Amulet** describes what it does - and it makes any magic currently active on the wearer hidden from divination magic.

### Detecting magic on the items carried by a creature

At first pass, it does seem like *[detect magic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/detect-magic)* should work here. But I think this is going to be up to some DM decision-making. Most of the time, items carried by a character are often considered part of their character (for instance, magic that causes fire generally stipulates that it won't burn things carried or worn.) However, that is a specific rule and may not be applicable at all times.

It's also important to note (thanks miniman!) that in order for *detect magic* to detect, the item must be visible. If it's not visible, then the spell definitely won't detect it.

In general, it does seem like divination magic won't hide magical items carried/worn by a character. But as with the fire example above, I think there is a case that it will hide those items. I think it's more fun that someone wearing this amulet is basically covering themselves and everything they've got in this magical protection.

### Your table, your rules

The only thing that really matters is that the spell doesn't work to detect items worn or carried, then that's fair to rule, but just remember to be fair, fun, and consistent if this sort of thing happens again.

Comment: @Miniman Relevant context for targeting of self vs. thing you're looking at: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/141052/will-an-amulet-of-proof-against-detection-and-location-protect-an-invisible-char?rq=1

Comment: As a clarification, something doesn't have to be visible to be sensed by detect magic. Nor does it need to be targeted. It needs to be visible in order to see it's aura (which also requires an action), not sense it's presence (which does not). The only thing that blocks you sensing it is a suitable thickness of a specified material.

Example: if a corpse has a magic ring in their pocket, the magic of this ring will be automagically sensed once within 30 feet of a creature with detect magic up. If it's wrapped in a thin sheet of lead, it won't be. That's clearly RAW + RAI.