# While wearing an Amulet of Proof Against Detection and Location, can I cast Divination spells with a range of Self?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, targeting, divination

Consider the situation: I am wearing an [Amulet of Proof against Detection and Location](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/4569-amulet-of-proof-against-detection-and-location), giving me the following effect:

> While wearing this amulet, you are hidden from divination magic. You can't be targeted by such magic or perceived through magical scrying sensors.

I want to cast the *[detect magic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/detect-magic)* spell, which has a range of self. Am I correct in assuming that the spell targets me, and thus I will be unable to cast it until I remove it? None of the existing answers cover the eventuality where you are *casting* the spell, only whether or not you show up to *somebody else* with it.

Comment: Related: "[How does an Amulet of Proof against Detection and Location interact with the Detect Magic spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/144357)" and "[Does Nondetection protect you from divination attack spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/190900)"

Comment: I closed this as a dupe because the questions, at least to me, are identical. "If I cast a *nondetection* spell on me can I also cast spells like *detect magic* on myself?" vs (paraphrase) "If I wear an Amulet can I also cast spells like *detect magic* on myself?". Where *nondetection* states "The target can't be targeted by any divination magic" and the Amulet states "You can't be targeted by [divination magic]"

Comment: If you feel the existing answers to the linked duplicate are inadequate, you may bounty the question to attract new answers with more details. This question is an exact duplicate of that one.