# Can an invisible creature with the Mind Blank spell cast on it be seen by a creature with the True Seeing spell cast on it?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, vision-and-light, invisibility

[True Seeing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-seeing) is a divination spell that states:

> For the duration, the creature has truesight [...]

While [Mind Blank](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mind-blank) states:

> Until the spell ends, one willing creature you touch is immune to psychic damage, any effect that would sense its emotions or read its thoughts, divination spells, and the charmed condition. The spell even foils wish spells and spells or effects of similar power used to affect the target's mind or to gain information about the target.

Let's say that the Rogue had Invisibility and Mind Blank cast on him, and the Wizard cast True Seeing on himself. How do these spells interact?

The discussion at my table hinges on the fact that True Seeing doesn't target or affect the Mind Blanked rogue, so his immunity is not relevant. The Wizard would simply gain Truesight and would spot him. Is this correct?

Comment: So is the question here what "being immune to Divination spells" means/entails?

Comment: @Medix2 The broader question, I suppose so. But applied to my particular example :P

Comment: Related (essentially the same question but with *Nondetection* instead of *Mind Blank*): https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/80845/do-nondetection-and-invisibility-protect-you-from-true-seeing/139695#139695

Comment: @RyanThompson Great find. I'm VTCing this question

Comment: Related (targeting is a mess): "[What Counts as a target for a spell](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/152115)"

Comment: I believe these questions are different due to different wording. One says you can't be targeted by spells, the other says you are immune to spells

Comment: Yeah, I agree it's not necessarily a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## *Mind blank* foils *true seeing*.

*Mind blank* states:

> **The spell even foils** wish spells and **spells** or effects of similar power **used** to affect the target’s mind or **to gain information about the target**.

If *true seeing* is used to gain information (current position, appearance, etc.) about the target of *mind blank*, then it is foiled.

Usually you can see the target of *mind blank* because your eyes are not "spells or effects of similar power", but if the target is also invisible by some other means, then *true seeing* is foiled and the target remains invisible to you.

Comment: By extension wouldn't this foil literally any spell like *firebolt* which would reveal the creature's location if they were hit?

Comment: @Medix2 I'm not sure what you mean, *firebolt* doesn't reveal the location of the creature it hits

Comment: If I hit a creature with *firebolt* I would know where it is. If I see a creature with *true seeing* I would know where it is. Just as you can see a creature, so too could you see where the *firebolt* stopped moving

Comment: @Medix2 to target a creature with *firebolt* you need to know what space it is in, which allows you to shoot (with disadvantage if the target is invisible). Whether you hit or not, you don't gain any new information, so there is no interaction with *mind blank*.

Comment: Yes it does have an interaction. You can aim a spell without knowing where a creature is, and fire in a random direction. If that spell hit an invisible creature you would thus gain the knowledge of where it is

Comment: [This](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/06/27/alter-self-mind-blank-vs-truesight-what-wins/) can complement your answer, found it after the question was closed yesterday

Comment: @Medix2 You'd gain knowledge that there's _something_ at that location, not that it is a specific creature.

Answer (score 1):

**The wizard with *true seeing* can see the *mind blanked* rogue.**

- The spell *true seeing* was cast upon (and affects) the *wizard* not the rogue.
- The *rogue is immune* to divination spells, which means divination spells cannot be successfully *cast* upon the rogue. From *mind blank*'s write up "The spell even foils wish spells and spells or effects of similar power used to affect the **target’s mind** or to gain information about the **target**," but the *true seeing* **targets the wizard** (not the rogue), granting the wizard "the ability to see things as they actually are." and "For the duration, the creature **has truesight**..." From the *PHB* definition of truesight: "A creature with truesight can, out to a specific range, see in normal and magical darkness, **see invisible creatures and objects**..." *Mind blank* does not grant invisibility, and therefore does not prevent a *mind blanked* target from being seen by those with truesight.

Comment: What do you think of the logic in [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/81025/40516)?

Comment: @RyanThompson Thank you for the link! I think both the linked OP and the linked answer are playing loosey-goosey with the straightforward language of the rules (e.g., the spell *true seeing* **targets** the wizard, not the rogue), and I disagree with it.

Comment: Supporting that this is what being immune to a divination spell means would help*

Comment: @Medix2 Edited a bit.

Comment: The uses "target" in the spell description are referring to the target of *mind blank* not a generic spell. It would've said "gain information about **their** target" if it meant all spells. Also you have not justified that "being immune to divination spells" means exactly "cannot be targeted by divination spells" which is the phrasing that *nondetection* uses which is discussed in this question: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/80845

Comment: @Medix2 Unlike the wording of the write up for *mind blank*, *nondetection* says explicitly "The target [of *nondetection*] can’t be targeted by any divination magic or perceived through magical scrying sensors." *Mind blank* is not affected by someone else having truesight, but the *invisibility* of someone covered by *mind blank* is seen through.

Comment: I agree the wordings are different but your sentence "The rogue is immune to divination spells, which means divination spells cannot be successfully cast upon the rogue." effectively equates them with no proof/logic provided.

Comment: Also you say: "The spell even foils [...] spells [...] used to [...] gain information **about the target**, but the true seeing **targets the wizard**". It doesn't matter what *true seeing* targets. The description is saying that spells cannot grant information about the target of ***mind blank***.

Comment: @Medix2 I think that is a spurious use of "not grant information," which I read to address the effects of spells like *locate creature* which have write ups describing specific kinds of information provided by the spell. Contrast with someone casting *locate creature* on a (visible) target currently under *mind blank*: the caster would *necessarily* gain the information that the target cannot be affected by *locate creature*.

Comment: @Medix2 "effectively equates them with no proof/logic provided." The logic is in the plain-language reading of the phrase, and the ethos of "spells do just what they say they do, no more, no less" of 5e.